# spring.application.json is not working on windows os

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am setting system property `spring.application.json={"foo": "bar"}` in my spring boot application. This works well in all linux OS but not in windows. Is there something specific to windows?

When I run my spring boot, in linux I see

`INFO eEncryptablePropertySourcesPostProcessor : Converting PropertySource spring.application.json [org.springframework.core.env.MapPropertySource] to EncryptableMapPropertySourceWrapper`

but not in windows.

Comment: What do you see in `Windows`?

Comment: I don't see it @MehrajMalik

Comment: On windows, you have to  enclose JSON within double quotes i.e. spring.application.json="{\"foo\": \"bar\"}" . Example [here](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-boot/json-env-properties.html)

Answer (score 0):

Windows users should use the SET instruction to set the environment variable first

Comment: Try adding a simple example to your answer.